# How to make a 3D list using a csv file for the first two dimensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not very familiar with python, and so googling and educated guessing led me to try for a list comprehensions solution but there's something wrong with my format I imagine. This line gives me a syntax error so is there a way to fix it?

```
    3dCSV = [[0 for _ in range(2)]list(csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1])))]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

The csv is literally just a 2D array of numbers.

example:

```
    9 4 3 5 4
    3 9 4 7 2
    4 1 6 3 4
    3 4 8 2 8
```

just want to add a third dimension on top of that to hold  0 or 1 (basically a boolean) so that I can test `list[a][b][0]` and depending on the output I get, put 0 or 1 in `list[a][b][1]`. I'm not really sure how to give a better example?

Comment: hi there :) it's hard to determine the intent... could you give an example of what one row of what your csv is supposed to look like?

Comment: Please provide example CSV and the expected result, as it stands it's impossible provide meaningful answer.

Comment: don't know what you are trying to do, please provide an example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short example that just reads the lines from file, splits them on whitespace and converts every item to pair `[int, None]`:

```
import pprint

with open('source.csv') as f:
    res = [[[int(x), None] for x in row.split()] for row in f]

res[1][2][1] = (res[1][2][0] % 2 == 0)
pprint.pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
[[[9, None], [4, None], [3, None], [5, None], [4, None]],
 [[3, None], [9, None], [4, True], [7, None], [2, None]],
 [[4, None], [1, None], [6, None], [3, None], [4, None]],
 [[3, None], [4, None], [8, None], [2, None], [8, None]]]
```

In above `for row in f` just reads the lines from file one by one:

```
>>> rows = [row for row in f]
>>> rows
['9 4 3 5 4\n', '3 9 4 7 2\n', '4 1 6 3 4\n', '3 4 8 2 8\n']
```

Then `for x in row.split()` uses `str.split` to split the rows at every whitespace:

```
>>> rows = [[x for x in row.split()] for row in f]
>>> rows
[['9', '4', '3', '5', '4'], ['3', '9', '4', '7', '2'], ['4', '1', '6', '3', '4'], ['3', '4', '8', '2', '8']]
```

Since we want to have `[int, None]` elements in the final result instead of strings we convert every element accordingly:

```
>>> rows = [[[int(x), None] for x in row.split()] for row in f]
>>> print(*rows, sep='\n')
[[9, None], [4, None], [3, None], [5, None], [4, None]]
[[3, None], [9, None], [4, None], [7, None], [2, None]]
[[4, None], [1, None], [6, None], [3, None], [4, None]]
[[3, None], [4, None], [8, None], [2, None], [8, None]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? So whenever you call 3dcsv[a][b] it will reply True or False either way you set it. To change everything to False just replace True with False:

```
import csv
filename='something.csv' #Enter your filename
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    _3dcsv = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

for index, i in enumerate(_3dcsv):
    for index2, e in enumerate(i):
        _3dcsv[index][index2]={e:True} #or false
```

output:

```
[[{'1': True}, {'2': True}, {'3': True}, {'4': True}, {'5': True}],
 [{'4': True}, {'5': True}, {'2': True}, {'3': True}, {'5': True}],
 [{'4': True}, {'5': True}, {'6': True}, {'7': True}, {'1': True}]]
```

Comment: Did you run the code? [Names](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) can't start with decimal numbers and `csv` uses `,` as default separator.

Comment: @niemmi Sorry, I changed the name when I posted here since that was what @ Kalahira used. Completely forgot about it, I ran the code with my own variable names so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be dealing with CSV files a lot and array style data then you should look into [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) which is an array/math library for python. The easiest way to install it and python would be to install the **Anaconda Python distribution** from https://www.continuum.io/downloads

with numpy installed do this:

```
import numpy as np
```

you need to specify the data type (int for integer or float for 
decimal  like numbers) if your numbers not floats as float is the default.

```
arr2d = np.loadtxt(sys.argv[1], dtype=int)
print(arr2d)
```

outputs:

```
array([[9, 4, 3, 5, 4],
       [3, 9, 4, 7, 2],
       [4, 1, 6, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 8, 2, 8]])
```

now create a boolean array of the same shape where all values greater than 3 (as an example.

```
arrbool = arr2d > 3
print(arrbool)
```

outputs

```
[[ True  True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True False]
 [ True False  True False  True]
 [False  True  True False  True]]
```

use the arrbool array as a mask to set only values in True position
to some number (make a copy of the array or you will modify the original).

```
arrcopy = arr2d.copy()
arrcopy[arrbool] = 1
print(arrcopy)
```

outputs:

```
array([[1, 1, 3, 1, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 3, 1],
       [3, 1, 1, 2, 1]])
```